# SQL Server create index on system table sys.sysschobjs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, ddl

I'm trying to create a non-clustered index on a system base table `sys.sysschobjs` and get this error :

> Index cannot be created on object 'sys.sysschobjs' because the object is not a user table or view.

I tried with DAC and with single-user-mode as well

Is there a way to create indexes on system base tables ?

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure how much clearer that error could possibly be. Is there some part of that message that isn't clear? And why do you think you need to create an index on that table?

Comment: @marc_s sys.sysschobjs is a system base table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables

Comment: I suppose if you REALLY wanted to index a sys table for some reason you could just make a materialized view over it and then index that?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock SQL Server also does not support indexed views over sys objects.

Comment: @SeanLange I have user database with 800k objects  (yes I know , bad design ). Can not turn on IntelliSense  because of heavy system tables queries...

Comment: LOL. That sounds pretty horrific to me. I just looked at our huge third party ERP DB and there are just over 100,000 there. Even the native intellisense works pretty fast there. Have you tried any third party intellisense options?

Comment: I didn't try any third party tools , they should query the same object , so I'm not sure it will perform better.

Answer (score 3):

To Sean's point, no, you cannot create indexes on system tables or system views.

**Update 1:** Because Microsoft says so:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/master-database

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables

The idea is that the system databases, like master, are required in order for SQL Server to start. As a result, users are prohibited from making changes to these system objects that MS's developers have built in order to prevent users from blowing up the server. Microsoft doesn't explicitly say this, but it seems evident in the restrictions that they list on their site.

If you are questioning the performance of the system databases then you might want to check the following link for creating a maintenance plan:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/maintenance-plans/use-the-maintenance-plan-wizard

You can also run DBCC CHECKDB(master) to review the health of the database. For more information on how DBCC CHECKDB() works, see the following (it was written by the person who created the function):

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-complete-description-of-all-checkdb-stages/

**Update 2 - Final point:**

Read the two purple Important bubbles on the page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables

1.) The system base tables are used only within the SQL Server Database Engine and are not for general customer use. They are subject to change and compatibility is not guaranteed.

2.) Access to system base tables by using DAC is designed only for Microsoft personnel, and it is not a supported customer scenario.

This should resolve your question.

Comment: But... why not? The answer to this, would make this answer much more valuable than rewording the error message. There are other objects which aren't a user table or view which I would expect this to fail :)

Comment: @scsimon To be fair, the question asked was "is there a way" and I agree that the only right answer is **no**. I'm not sure you can blame the answerer for the question that was asked, or if it's the answerer's job to somehow make the question better by answering a question that wasn't asked. I'm also not sure you can get a "right" answer to the why question - that would be Microsoft internal info.

Comment: @AaronBertrand definitely wasn't blaming the answerer for the question above--I just thought it was a great opportunity to dive deeper. BTW--love all of your blogs.

Comment: @scsimon I have updated my answer. Please note that you asked whether or not it is possible to add indexes to system tables/views. This implies a yes or no answer. As a result, I have answered it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the system table I'm trying to create index on,is not on master database  , it is  on other user database . so no workaround ?

Comment: System base tables are contained in the master DB, but are hidden. You must have admin privileges to see them. But, same result, you cannot index them - leave them alone.

Comment: Correction: many base tables, including the one that you are asking about, exist in all databases on the server. But, see Update 2 regarding the ability to access these base tables.

Comment: @YossiM You might want to consider marking your question as answered.